# Turn Based Asynchronous Games Server

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a server for Asynchronous turn based mobile game like `GameCenter`.
I don't use GameCenter because i need to customize login screen and user can login with Facebook, Google+, etc. So does anyone know any server like this.

I found `Phonton` from `exitgame`, `appwarp` and many but none of it matchs my required

EDITTED:

After many weeks searching I have found an amazing thing is

[Hydra](http://hydra.agoragames.com)

It has everything I need. Check it out

Answer (score 2):

There are several other options including `scoreloop`, `steam`, and `geosophic`

Comment: tks for your help but these are not what I looking for